Place a node at a position perpendicular away from a curve, using coordinates from the tikz library calc
I want to place a node at a position perpendicular away from a curve, using coordinates from \usetikzlibrary{calc}. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724636/319072.
I do not know why, but when I try this, they are not positioned perpendicularly from the - in this case, a line.
How can I overcome this?
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Reference lines
\draw (0,0) -- (55:3);
\draw[dashed] (55:1.5) -- ++(55+90:3);

% Does not work
\path[%
decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {
\node at (0,1) {A};},
},
postaction={decorate}
] ($(0,0) + (55+90:1)$) -- ++($(55:3) + (55+90:1)$);

% But this does
\path[%
decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {
\node at (0,1) {A};
\node at (0,2) {B};},
},
postaction={decorate}
] (0,0) -- ++(55:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I'm not entirely clear what exactly you're trying to construct, but your reference lines don't correspond to the path where you use coordinate calculations to ascertain the points. If we add those explicitly in red, the 'misplaced' node looks to be roughly where you'd expect.

\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Reference lines
  \draw (0,0) -- (55:3);
  \draw [red] ($(0,0) + (55+90:1)$) coordinate (a) -- ++($(55:3) + (55+90:1)$);
  \draw[dashed] (55:1.5) -- ++(55+90:3);
  \draw [red,dotted] (a) -- ++(55:3) -- ++(55+90:1);

  % Does not work
  \path[%
    decoration={markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {
      \node [anchor=center] at (0,1) {A};},
    },
    postaction={decorate},
  ] ($(0,0) + (55+90:1)$) -- ++($(55:3) + (55+90:1)$);

  % But this does
  \path[%
    decoration={markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {
        \node [anchor=center] at (0,1) {A};
      \node [anchor=center] at (0,2) {B};},
    },
    postaction={decorate}
  ] (0,0) -- ++(55:3);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Weird! I'm using ($(0,0) + (55+90:1)$) -- ++($(55:3) + (55+90:1)$) to draw a perpendicularly spaced from the line (0,0) -- (55:3). It doesn't seem to be doing that though. The objective from this is to label a path's projection.

Ahhh, I'm using the ++ syntax! That means I don't neet the (55:3) part, because my command used ++. Sorry for that

@Jasper yeah. that's why I added the dotted lines.
